# Hadoop Mapreduce Naive Bayes Classifier in netbeans

Tags: java, hadoop

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.<clinit>   (ProtobufRpcEngine.java:73)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

I got the above error when I try to run the program using Naive Bayes Classifier using Map reduce.. I have imported all the necessary jar files... I already surfed for many answers and come to know that its because of protobuf version mismatch but I still have the correct version of jar....

Hadoop version : 2.6.0
Compiled with protoc : 2.5.0

Pls can any one help me out...... I am madly in need to execute it ....